# narrowing OU to only return users from all results

Tags: powershell, ou

so I currently have code that returns the ADUsers of a company. I want to narrow the results that it brings back to only show the users and not the other results that its returning.

I have the following code

```bsh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$fmtADUser = 

      @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Name";Width=25},
      @{Expression={$_.UserPrincipalName};Label="User Principal Name";Width=30},
      @{Expression={$_.Created};Label="Created On";Width=30},
      @{Expression={$_.lastLogonDate};Label="Last Logged On Date";Width=30}

$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(160,5000)

Get-ADUser -Filter *  -Properties * | Format-Table -Property $fmtADUser
```

Comment: Can you explain what your current code is not doing for you? The only thing I see unideal is using `-Properties *` as it returns too much data from ADWS. It should be `-Properties Created,LastLogonDate` instead.

Comment: In addition, from the title of your question, I assume you want to add parameter `-SearchBase <DN of OU>`

Comment: Yes I need to use -SearchBase to narrow my results to only return the actual users at the company and not computers like “administrator” or “guest”

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to pull the Names/users you can try

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Format-Table Name -A
```

or

comment out/remove the other lines apart from Name label as follows from the hashtable.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    $fmtADUser = 
  @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Name";Width=25}
  #@{Expression={$_.UserPrincipalName};Label="User Principal Name";Width=30},
  #@{Expression={$_.Created};Label="Created On";Width=30},
  #@{Expression={$_.lastLogonDate};Label="Last Logged On Date";Width=30}

$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(160,5000)

Get-ADUser -Filter *  -Properties * | Format-Table -Property $fmtADUser
```

Both will have the same results but the upper one will be little faster as per my test on my local.